# ActiveMQ - How to retrive consumerId from message from ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed

Tags: activemq-classic

is it possible to retrive consumerId from message received from "ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.[queue-name]" topic?

When a consumer consumes a message from a queue, an advisory message is placed in topic ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.[queue-name].
After I checked a message retrieved from ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.[queue-name] I realised that there is no consumerId.

My custom MessageListener for ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.[queue-name] has method:

```html
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
  ActiveMQMessage msg = (ActiveMQMessage)message;
  // Retrives the MessageListener's connection which consumed a message from Advisory Topic
  msg.getConnection().getClientID();
  // Retrives the Producer's connection which place a message into a queue
  ((ActiveMQMessage)msg.getDataStructure()).getConnection().getClientID();
  // How to retrive a consumerId which consumed a message from the queue?
}
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not available from the advisory, only the connection ID is available.